# Live Video Preview in Video Recorder app in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, video-recording

I am writing a **Video Recorder app in Windows Phone 8.1 (RT)**.

How to get live preview of video from camera on app?
Which controls to use?

I tried using:

```
    CameraCaptureUI dialog = new CameraCaptureUI();
```

But its supported in Windows 8.1 and not Windows Phone 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Try Using Video Brush.

Just Put the Video brush inside the Canvas and you can have full control over thhe UI and as well as code behind.

Just for Reference : http://wp.qmatteoq.com/how-to-save-a-picture-captured-with-the-new-cameras-api-in-the-camera-roll-in-windows-phone-8/

Hope it Helps

Answer (score -1):

**C#:**

```
  LiveVideoPreview.Source = _mediaCapture;
    await _mediaCapture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

**XAML:**

```
<CaptureElement x:Name="LiveVideoPreview" 
                            Height="500">
            </CaptureElement>
```